# Datanode machines disks size

Tags: linux, redhat, hadoop, hdfs

is it important that ( workers ) datanode machines disks will be with the same size?

for example

we have ambari cluster with 3 workers machines ( datanode machines )

each datanode machine have 10 disks ( 7 disk with 50G and the 3 disks with 48G )

```
lsblk | grep sd | grep disk
sda                8:0    0   150G  0 disk  <-- OS disk
sdb                8:16   0    50G  0 disk 
sdc                8:32   0    50G  0 disk 
sdd                8:48   0    50G  0 disk 
sde                8:64   0    50G  0 disk 
sdf                8:80   0    50G  0 disk 
sdg                8:96   0    50G  0 disk
sdh                8:112  0    50G  0 disk
sdi                8:128  0    48G  0 disk
sdj                8:144  0    48G  0 disk
sdk                8:160  0    48G  0 disk
```

is it critical to ambari cluster to work with diff size on workers machines ?

second:

what about each worker machines have disks with the same size but disks are diff between workers ?

Comment: Disk size can be similar or different. There is no issue with it.

Comment: can you explain why it no make diff?